# split List of values based on value

Tags: java, collections

I have a list of objects(Person in this case) and I want to split them into a list of list Person objects based on value. In the example given below, I have a Person object with name, id and Address object. The address object has a house number, Street Id. Now I want to split them based on Street Id in address object using collections API. I tried grouping by, partitioning in collections, but couldn't get it work.  I want to use only Java 8. No third party.

Expected result :

```
[ [person1, person2, person3] , [person4, person5], [person6] ]
```

Thanks.

```
package testapplication2;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 *
 *
 */
public class JavaCollections {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    JavaCollections c = new JavaCollections();
    c.test1();
  }

  public void test1() {
    List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<>();
    Address address1 = new Address(1, "X Street", 100);
    Address address2 = new Address(2, "X Street", 100);
    Address address3 = new Address(3, "X Street", 100);
    Address address4 = new Address(4, "Y Street", 101);
    Address address5 = new Address(5, "Y Street", 101);
    Address address6 = new Address(6, "Z Street", 102);
    persons.add(new Person(1, "P1", address1));
    persons.add(new Person(2, "P2", address2));
    persons.add(new Person(3, "P3", address3));
    persons.add(new Person(4, "P4", address4));
    persons.add(new Person(5, "P5", address5));
    persons.add(new Person(6, "P6", address6));
  }

  public class Person {

    public int personId;
    private String name;

    private Address address;

    public Person() {

    }

    public Person(int personId, String name, Address address) {
      super();
      this.personId = personId;
      this.name = name;
      this.address = address;
    }

    public int getPersonId() {
      return personId;
    }

    public void setPersonId(int personId) {
      this.personId = personId;
    }

    public String getName() {
      return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
      this.name = name;
    }

    public Address getAddress() {
      return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(Address address) {
      this.address = address;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
      return "Person{" + "personId=" + personId + ", name=" + name + ", address=" + address + '}';
    }

  }

  public class Address {

    public Address() {

    }

    public Address(int houseNumber, String streetName, int streetId) {
      this.houseNumber = houseNumber;
      this.streetId = streetId;
      this.streetName = streetName;
    }

    private int houseNumber;
    private String streetName;
    private int streetId;

    public int getHouseNumber() {
      return houseNumber;
    }

    public void setHouseNumber(int houseNumber) {
      this.houseNumber = houseNumber;
    }

    public String getStreetName() {
      return streetName;
    }

    public void setStreetName(String streetName) {
      this.streetName = streetName;
    }

    public int getStreetId() {
      return streetId;
    }

    public void setStreetId(int streetId) {
      this.streetId = streetId;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
      return "Address{" + "houseNumber=" + houseNumber + ", streetName=" + streetName + ", streetId=" + streetId + '}';
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: It seems to me, conceptually, that you basically want something that does the opposite of flatMap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution for your requirement is the usage of `stream().collect()` with a `groupingBy` call on the `person.address.streetId` field as a key.

This code should do it:

```
final List<List<Person>> groupedPersons = persons.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(o -> o.address.streetId))
        .entrySet().stream()
        .map(Map.Entry::getValue).collect(Collectors.toList());
// Code for printing out
groupedPersons.forEach(people -> {
    System.out.print("[");
    System.out.print(people.stream().map(person -> String.format("person%d", person.personId)).collect(Collectors.joining(",")));
    System.out.print("]");
});
```

Here is a full example which you can run:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Partitions {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<>();
        Address address1 = new Address(1, "X Street", 100);
        Address address2 = new Address(2, "X Street", 100);
        Address address3 = new Address(3, "X Street", 100);
        Address address4 = new Address(4, "Y Street", 101);
        Address address5 = new Address(5, "Y Street", 101);
        Address address6 = new Address(6, "Z Street", 102);
        persons.add(new Person(1, "P1", address1));
        persons.add(new Person(2, "P2", address2));
        persons.add(new Person(3, "P3", address3));
        persons.add(new Person(4, "P4", address4));
        persons.add(new Person(5, "P5", address5));
        persons.add(new Person(6, "P6", address6));
        final List<List<Person>> groupedPersons = persons.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(o -> o.address.streetName))
            .entrySet().stream()
            .map(Map.Entry::getValue).collect(Collectors.toList());
        groupedPersons.forEach(people -> {
            System.out.print("[");
            System.out.print(people.stream().map(person -> String.format("person%d", person.personId)).collect(Collectors.joining(",")));
            System.out.print("]");
        });

    }

    public static class Person {

        public int personId;
        private String name;

        private Address address;

        public Person() {

        }

        public Person(int personId, String name, Address address) {
            super();
            this.personId = personId;
            this.name = name;
            this.address = address;
        }

        public int getPersonId() {
            return personId;
        }

        public void setPersonId(int personId) {
            this.personId = personId;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public Address getAddress() {
            return address;
        }

        public void setAddress(Address address) {
            this.address = address;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Person{" + "personId=" + personId + ", name=" + name + ", address=" + address + '}';
        }

    }

    public static class Address {

        private int houseNumber;
        private String streetName;
        private int streetId;
        public Address() {

        }
        public Address(int houseNumber, String streetName, int streetId) {
            this.houseNumber = houseNumber;
            this.streetId = streetId;
            this.streetName = streetName;
        }

        public int getHouseNumber() {
            return houseNumber;
        }

        public void setHouseNumber(int houseNumber) {
            this.houseNumber = houseNumber;
        }

        public String getStreetName() {
            return streetName;
        }

        public void setStreetName(String streetName) {
            this.streetName = streetName;
        }

        public int getStreetId() {
            return streetId;
        }

        public void setStreetId(int streetId) {
            this.streetId = streetId;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Address{" + "houseNumber=" + houseNumber + ", streetName=" + streetName + ", streetId=" + streetId + '}';
        }

    }
}
```

This will print out:

```
[person4,person5][person6][person1,person2,person3]
```

**Update:**

If you want to preserve the order in which it was added to the initial list, you can provide a collector which supplies a `java.util.LinkedHashSet` - a data structure which preserves uniqueness and the original order of insertion.

The grouping code would look like this:

```
final List<Set<Person>> groupedPersons = persons.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(o -> o.address.streetId, 
                Collector.of(() -> new LinkedHashSet<Person>(), HashSet::add, (s1, s2) -> {
            s1.addAll(s2);
            return s1;
        })))
        .entrySet().stream()
        .map(Map.Entry::getValue).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If you use this code in the example above it will print out:

```
[person1,person2,person3][person4,person5][person6]
```

Comment: Is it possible to maintain the order ( ascending order of street id) or in the order in which it was added to the initial list? In this example, the persons are added in the ascending order street id. After splitting, when it is printed, it shows in different order. Just curious to know if there is an ordered list kind of API. No answers, no issues.

Comment: Yes, you can preserve the original order in which the entries were added. Please check the updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```
    List< List<Person> > groups = new ArrayList<>( persons.stream().collect( 
    Collectors.groupingBy( p -> p.getAddress().getStreetId() ) ).values() );
```

Alternatively by @shmosel:

```
    List< List<Person> > groups = persons.stream().collect( Collectors.collectingAndThen(
    Collectors.groupingBy( p -> p.getAddress().getStreetId() ), 
    m -> new ArrayList<>( m.values() ) ) );
```

Comment: Would this not create a `Map<Integer, List<Person>>`? (Corrected key type.) I think the OP wants it in something like `List<List<Person>>`

Comment: I mean, I think that a `Map` would probably be preferable to nested `List`s, but OP wants what OP wants. :P (Upvoted.)

Comment: Alternatively, `collectingAndThen(groupingBy(p -> p.getAddress().getStreetId()), m -> new ArrayList<>(m.values()))`.

Comment: Sure @shmosel. I will add that approach to the answer as well.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this, you need to

- use a `Stream` of your list,
- then `groupBy` the `id` of the `Address`, all the Person with the same `adressId` will be together in a `Map<Integer,List<Person>>`
- then you get the `values` (all the `List<Person>` and collecth them together)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JavaCollections c = new JavaCollections();
    List<Person> persons = c.test1();
    List<List<Person>> res = new ArrayList<>(persons .stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(o -> o.getAddress().getStreetId())).values());
    System.out.println(test);
 }
```

And change  `test1()` to

```
public static List<Person> test1() {
    ...; 
    return persons;
}
```

to return the list